# How can I move mysites to a new location

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I recently restored my content and was instructed to create mysites in a different location than was originally used. Now I have several users mysites in /personal.  The new desired location is /mysites. From what I found in the documentation I should back them up and restore them to the new location.

Here's what I've done:

- *Backup individual site collection for user mysite*

stsadm -o backup -url "https://myUrl/personal/john_smith" -filename johnsmith.bkup

- *Restore individual site collection for user mysite*

stsadm -o restore -url "https://myUrl/mysites/john_smith" -filename johnsmith.bkup -overwrite

The result of this and the problem is when i enumerate sites i end up with this:

`<Site Url="https://myUrl/mysites" Owner="domainname\john.smith" ContentDatabase="WSS_Content_MySites" StorageUsedMB="1.6" StorageWarningMB="90000" StorageMaxMB="100000" />`

it leaves off the username part of the url. and if I restore more that one they want to overwrite each other.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem moving mysites around.

Are your sites currently on the same database as the SSP?

We followed this [blog](http://blogs.technet.com/victorbutuza/archive/2009/02/10/how-to-move-an-ssp.aspx) - Issue B, but had issues with the backup / restore, so we used export / import instead, which worked well. The only problem was that the user 'profile' - all the custom information that people filled in was blank, but all documents etc were included.

Also, if you're on W2k8 you might need to turn off 'User Account Control' to get stsadm the permissions it'll need, just remember to turn it back on. ( Control Panel --> User Accounts --> Turn User Account Control on or off )

Hope it helps.

Sam